# Best practise: Wrap a template in another template in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to do the following:

I have a recurring UI pattern called `<overlay></overlay>`
This overlay is dynamically created by a directive **dir1** from a templateUrl.

Let's assume now I have a second UI element called `<gallery></gallery>`which is also dynamically created by a directive **dir2**.

Is it possible to pass the gallery template into the overlay creating something like:

```
 <overlay>
      <gallery></gallery>
 </overlay>
```

**Note that the Element overlay and gallery will be replaced by the template from its respective directive.**

Here is a small Plunk with the updated problem ==> http://plnkr.co/edit/Bu2cwXYVQXKmjDVXaHuK?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `ng-transclude`. Something like:

```
angular.module("myModule", []).
    directive("overlay", function () {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            transclude: true,
            // or  templateUrl: ...
            template: '<ul class="u" ng-transclude></ul>',
            replace: true
        };
    }).
    directive("gallery", function () {
        return {
            require: "^overlay",
            restrict: "E",
            scope:{cls:'@'},
            transclude: true,
            // or  templateUrl: ...
            template: '<li class="l"><button class="{{cls}}" ng-transclude></button></li>',
            replace: true
        };
    });
```

Anyways, here is good example for your needs:

Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UWEsN/21/)**</kbd>

Comment: Ah great, I am a donkey :D I forgot to put the transclude on the template element. ng-transclude did it. Also +1 for the require : "^overlay".

Comment: Just reopened the question: What if i have content inside my <overlay> ike a close button. Currently it will be replaced. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: @Interactionist can you demonstrate that in Fiddle I posted?

Comment: Sure. I also updated my Plunk if that helps ==>  http://plnkr.co/edit/Bu2cwXYVQXKmjDVXaHuK?p=preview

Comment: Here it goes: http://jsfiddle.net/UWEsN/22/
Strange but it is working in your example.

Comment: Okay, I updated your fiddle. And I also changed to the newest version of angular 1.2.1.

Comment: Nope, it is borked. Seems like there is a different behavior when using the new AngularJS 1.2.1. Your original fiddle was using 1.0.6

Comment: Yes, I actually made the same changes. Weird that it is applying it to the first ng-transclude found in the template. Anyway, thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing transclude: true but you are not using transclusion anywhere

So instead of your code you should write as below

template: `"<div class='my-generic-overlay' ng-transclude>This should be replaced by the myGallery template</div>"`